# 403 Forbidden error

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-11.10

I do have Ubuntu desktop 10.04 which all my php web application folder resides at the var/www,copying all files to ubuntu desktop 11.10 var/www folder and run it at the browser with url: "http://localhost/somewebapplication" it gives me (403 Forbidden).

The Apache MySQL PHP already installed and running just fine, just to test I create a php file that displays a phpinfo() at sub-folder var/www/test/ and access it from the browser with url "http://localhost/test" it show's the php information.

what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you add an excerpt of your error log?

Comment: What do the directory/file permissions look like on the `somewebapplication` directory?

Comment: Logs and config files are the only way we're going to solve this.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is my first time to use ubuntu desktop which my boss needs to transfer the files from one to another. By the way how can I get those logs?

Comment: yes Sir. qweet "somewebapplication" is a example directory under the var/www.

Comment: The error logs say's: (13)Permission denied var/www/Enchanted Kingdom/.htaccesspcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file. ensure it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest reading this: [About linux permissions](http://ag.arizona.edu/ecat/web/permissions.html) first 
then this [Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151590/what-is-the-default-permission-for-var-www) to find out what to set, as poster had similar problem, as you have.

Hope this helps.